Inverted Sphere and 2:1 Mercator Projection
Yes, I know there are several threads on UV sphere Mercator projection - but they are all 5 or 10 years old - and they aren't for a inverted sphere (or a non-square uv). Many changes have been added to Blender, so I wonder what is the latest technique for creating:
Inverted sphere 2:1 mercator projection

2:1 ratio texture
Mapped to an inverted sphere  (poor man's skybox)

